# fortran acos function argument robustness

Tags: performance, fortran, trigonometry

Using fortran I have some routines that makes a number of calls to acos() and asin() as well as atan() etc. In a specific routine the calculation of the argument sometimes becomes illiegal (i.e. acos(1.0000001)) when using single precision variables. Using double precision this goes away, but with a speed slow down of about 50 - 70 %.
The only other way I can think of is to limit the argument:

```
arg3= arg1/arg2
if (angle > 1) then
  arg3= 1
else if (angle < -1) then
  arg3= -1
end if
angle= acos(arg3)
```

It seems though as a slow method of doing it. Is there a faster way? I.e. pre-limit `angle` so that it only takes values, in this case, between -1 and 1?

Edit: arguments are and results needs to be real (non-complex).

Comment: not for abs(arg) > 1 but complex is fine. But my result needs to be real.

Comment: The `min` and `max` intrinsics may well be faster then the `if` condition. You still risk the same problem even in double precision, it is probably just less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I might try

```
angle = acos(sign(min(abs(arg1/arg2),1.0),arg1/arg2))
```

and hope my compiler doesn't do `arg1/arg2` twice.  If it did, then I'd try precomputing it and using it twice.